# Migrate whole mysql to another server

Tags: mysql

I'm switching from a vps to another one and i need to migrate my mysql server.
Is there an easy way to backup/restore ALL databases and users (with permissions) at once?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Backup all databases with a character set:

```
mysqldump --all-databases \
          --add-drop-database \
          --add-drop-table \
          --default-character-set=utf8 \
          --user=myuser \
          --password=mypass \
          > youfile.sql
```

on older mysql use the latin1 character set.

Answer (score 1):

nvm, found it.

```
oldserver$ mysqldump mysql > mysql.sql
newserver$ mysql mysql < mysql.sql
newserver$ mysql 'flush privileges;'
```

from https://serverfault.com/a/36674/145487

Comment: with this you backup only the mysql database, but you need to backup all.

Answer (score 0):

you can backup the sql database with the following command:
`mysqldump -u root -p --database [your-database-name] > database_backup.sql`

Enter the above without the braces'[]' to backup your MySQL to the database_backup.sql file.

Later you can restore the database with the following command:
`mysql -u root -p [your_database_name] < database_backup.sql`

Comment: yeah, but i want backup all schemas and users...

Comment: hope this solves your problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848189/how-to-backup-whole-mysql-database-with-all-users-and-permissions-and-passwords